# typescript iterators playground error

Tags: typescript, iterator, iteration

I've got following code snippet:

```
var iterator: IterableIterator<string> = iterBreadth(tree);
for(var item of iterator){
  log(item)
}
```

`iterBreadth` is just a generator function that returns an iterator. Iterators in TypeScript are of type `IterableIterator<T>` where `T` is a `string` in my case.

My question is - why is the playground yelling at me at the `for..of` iterator loop line:

[image]

?

How come iterators are limited to arrays and string only?

---

I've found at the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html) that, when targeting ES3 or ES5, only arrays are allowed in `for..of` loops. But that doesn't explain what are strings doing in the playground erorr message.

---

Besides, I can see that typescript is having hard time transpiling `for..of`. The following code seems to be transpiled against arrays precisely, since it's just iterating over indices (0, 1, 2), not calling next:

```
var iterator = iterBreadth(tree);
for (var _i = 0, iterator_1 = iterator; _i < iterator_1.length; _i++) {
    var item = iterator_1[_i];
    log(item);
}
```

Comment: You need to target `es6` (or above) to be able to do that. But it seems that you know that already, so what exactly are you asking? Why targetting `es6` is needed?

Comment: @NitzanTomer nope, the question is about the error message. Why does it indicate `string` type?! I find it misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript 2.3 [added support for generators and the Iterator protocol for ES3 and ES5 targets](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html). With new `--downlevelIteration` option, your example compiles without errors:

```
tsc --lib es6 --target es5 --downlevelIteration t.ts
```

`--downlevelIteration` option is not available in typescript playground however.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a string characters using the for/of loop:

```
const str = "str";
for (let char of str) {
    console.log(char);
}
```

Outputs:

> s
>   t
>   r

That is the reason why the error message says `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Nitzan's answer covers a good solution. If, for any reason, you need to handle your iterable as an array you can use `Array.from()`

```
var iterator: IterableIterator<string> = iterBreadth(tree);
for(var item of Array.from(iterator)){
    log(item)
}
```